# How to change what the textfields based on what the user inputs?

Tags: javascript, textfield, acceleration

I am new to JavaScript and need to create an acceleration formula calculator. I need to first ask what variable the user would like to solve for in the acceleration formula (a=(v-u)/t) and then change textfields based on what the user inputs.

Here is what I have been working on.

```js
function showInputs() {
      var variable = document.getElementById("variableCal").value;
      
      if (variable === "v") {
        document.getElementById("u-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("a-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("t-input").style.display = "inline";
      } else if (variable === "u") {
        document.getElementById("v-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("a-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("t-input").style.display = "inline";
      } else if (variable === "t") {
        document.getElementById("v-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("u-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("a-input").style.display = "inline";
      }
      else if (variable === "a") {
        document.getElementById("t-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("u-input").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("v-input").style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <h1>Acceleration Calculator</h1>

    <form>
    <label for="variableCal">Choose a variable to solve for:</label>
    <select id="variableCal" onchange="showInputs()">
      <option value="v">v</option>
      <option value="u">u</option>
      <option value="t">t</option>
      <option value="t">a</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="u" id="u-input" style="display: none;">Value of u:</label>
    <input type="number" id="u" style="display: none;">
    <br>
    <label for="a" id="a-input" style="display: none;">Value of a:</label>
    <input type="number" id="a" style="display: none;">
    <br>
    <label for="t" id="t-input" style="display: none;">Value of t:</label>
    <input type="number" id="t" style="display: none;">
   
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="solveEquation()">Solve</button>
  </form>
  <div id="resultCal"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: How do change what the user can input based on what variable they want to solve for?

Comment: Set the `.disabled` and/or `.readonly` properties on the `HTMLInputElement` objects that you're already getting from `document.getElementById("u-input")` - but you shouldn't use only `.style` to control an element, because that only affects appearance, not functionality.

Comment: Also, are you using `<input type="number" />` or `<input type="text" />` - or `range` - or what? **Please post your HTML**

Comment: Thank you. I was using <input type="number" />.

Comment: What's the relevant HTML? Is there any other JavaScript, variables, functions...? Any CSS? If you share your (relevant) [mcve] code we can answer your question in a way that's specifically applicable to your own requirements, which also lets us show better examples to future visitors experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I just shared my HTML code. Hopefully that helps, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an 'input' event (something similar to this):

```
document.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    if (event.target && event.target.matches('input[type="number"]')) {
        
        // ... calc acceleration values

        document.getElementById("a-input").value = 'new-a-value';
        document.getElementById("v-input").value = 'new-v-value';
        document.getElementById("u-input").value = 'new-u-value';
        document.getElementById("t-input").value = 'new-t-value';
    }
}, false);
```

This will listen for any input made to any element on the page, but since we add the conditional statement to check the target type (`'input[type="text"]'` in this case), the listener will ignore inputs made to any other element types. That can be fine tuned if you needed to look at more specific elements.

Comment: IMO, the `input` event should be preferred over `change` as it allows for real-time updates in response to user-input instead of waiting for the user to tab-out of the input.

Comment: oh yeah, good call. I'll update. I just implemented `change` in another project, so it was fresh on my mind.

Comment: During the closing years of IE's reign (around IE9) we had to use the `change` event with checkboxes and radio buttons because it didn't correctly handle the `input` event - that's still burned into my mind :)